# Error when trying to retrieve Address by Coordinates from Google Maps API

Tags: php, google-maps, google-geocoder

I couldn't find a solution to retrieve the Address of a location based on it's coordinates.

Here is the code I'm using in PHP:

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=45.791788,24.147599&result_type=street_address&key=[API KEY]&sensor=false";
$response = file_get_contents($url, true);
```

The error response that I'm getting is:

```
{
   "error_message" : "API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I have no restrictions set for the API Key that I'm using.

Comment: @SorinHaidau, try single quotes.

Comment: @RonnieOosting I prefer single quotes too, but there is no reason why double quotes in this case would be the cause of any issues :)

Comment: "I have no restrictions set for the API Key that I'm using"  Google obviously disagrees.  Have you tried contacting their support?

Comment: Are you trying to access at localhost, or is it live?

Comment: @RonnieOosting It's live

Comment: Also, what result do you get if you just put that URL (including your key) in your browser?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=45.791788,24.147599&result_type=street_address&key=AIzaSyAOqVG4j6jvn63OdxxFw6-2GCSIGi32vrw&sensor=false

Comment: It is possible your IP is blocked to use your API key, can you try with another IP address? Also make sure that if you've set up IP Address Restrictions within the Developer Console, you've allowed the correct IP address, just click the project within the list and you'll see the allowed IPs.

Comment: I'd say you have two options.  1) Figure out why Google thinks that you _do_ have a restriction on that key.  2) Generate a fresh key and use that instead.

Comment: If I replace your key with one of mine that is unrestricted, the URL in the link above (in your comment) works.  Create a new key, if that still doesn't work, contact Google Support.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that there are two types of restrictions.  Application restrictions & API restrictions.
Although the error message was regarding the API Key, it was actually related to some restrictions of the Application. HTTP referrers (web sites) was checked but no domain names were defined.

I couldn't find a suitable format for my subdomain so I removed any Application restrictions and that did the trick.